# Google Sheets on PC Copy/paste using "Paste Values" (Crtl+shift+V) appears to work but numbers are not treated as numbers in GRAPHS

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, formatting, copy-paste

When I copy numbers using either "Edit/Copy" or "<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>" in Google Sheets on PC and then use "Edit/Paste/Special/Paste Values" or (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), the numbers are indeed pasted. They appear normal and are in the formula entry box as numbers, but they are not treated as numbers in GRAPHING.

The only way I can see that they are not "normal" is that they are Left aligned instead of Right aligned. By the way, the prior FORMAT of the cell doesn't change this behavior, but formatting the cell with the numbers in it can be used with FORMAT\NUMBER\"0.0" to make them normal.

I am otherwise either using "Format/Number/Automatic" or "Format/Number/"0.0"

This odd "invisible formatting survives copy pasting and EDIT\PASTE SPECIAL\ PASTE TRANSPOSED.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd> followed by <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`\`**</kbd>.

This should reset the formatting from whatever back to Automatic.

[image: 0]

Or use straight this combo:

1. <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd>
2. <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`O`**</kbd>
3. <kbd>**`N`**</kbd>
4. <kbd>**`N`**</kbd>

Comment: @BenjaminWade answer updated

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the first method to no effect. Pasted values remained abnormal and unrecognized as numbers, and left aligned, which showed that something was wrong with them. Your second suggestion works well, as a shortcut way of formatting them correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, and it somewhat addresses the problem, it requires a manual process and (I mean no disrespect) doesn't address the underlying problem.  I will accept the answer later if I can't find any other way of addressing this issue. I am attempting to automate the process and I can't be reforting manually all the time. I do appreciate the answer however.

Comment: @BenjaminWade you are welcome